# Avoid jQuery .click() scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using $.click() to simulate user interaction with some buttons. The problem is that in addition to simulating the user click, the function scrolls automatically to the element. Is there any way to avoid this?

I made a temporal fix but I don't like it because I have to add two lines and I don't want to add those lines every time I use $.click() in my app. This is what I did:

```
var current_scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.item').click();
$(window).scrollTop(current_scroll_position);
```

Comment: you can put those three lines into a function or override `.click()`

Comment: What does the click event look like that is associated with '.item'?

Comment: What causes it to scroll to the element?

Comment: Can you show this undesired scrolling example in jsfiddle?
https://jsfiddle.net/mj7vzwep/

Answer (score -2):

Check out event delegation with .on() rather than .click():
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Or do something like this:

```
    $('.item').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I may be misunderstanding what you're asking for though.